# Payfort Channel not configured error while integrate live account

Tags: php, laravel, payment, gateway, payfort

I had integrated `payfort payment gateway` in my `Laravel 5` project using `laravel-payfort library` (https://github.com/wshurafa/laravel-payfort). It worked fine while using sandbox account. But when switch to live or original account it ends up in error payment with an error message:

> Channel not configured for selected payment option

I am using the redirection channel I think. 
[Here is the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qi9E2.png)

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I had contacted the payfort team.I can solve the issue by their instructions. These are the steps they provided.

Go to : Technical settings tab , click on add Technical settings , choose channel Redirection , status active , add payment option Visa and MasterCard

Configure your Direct Transaction Feedback URL in its field , and any URL from your domain in the following fields : Notification Transaction Feedback , Redirection URL

Choose Send Response Parameters : YES , Return URL Type : GET

Answer (score 0):

-> You need to ask to pay fort support for add the channel in to your account for redirection channel. if its not added.

-> for live and test urls are different, Please check this too.

-> if channel is added describe more. About Technical settings and Payment Option in your payfort account.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.I had contacted payfort team.Issue is now resolved by changing technical settings